# Extract content between 2 strings

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a simple (hopefully) Batch file, that can search an XML file and extract content from between 2 strings.

The XML file always contains the following once:
`<NAME>John Smith</NAME>`

This will be somewhere inside the XML, but may be in different place/line each time. If possible I need the name extracted and made into a variable.

Edit
So far I have been playing with findstr `for /F "tokens=2 delims=<> %%a in ('findstr "<name>" C:\list.xml') do set name=%%a echo %name%` The name may be 3 or 4 words and sometimes contain - The above works sometimes but only if on it's own separate line, but that is not always the case.

`<NAME>John Smith</NAME>` is always together and always on the same line, but not always on its own separate line.

Example XML data (all on one line) `<?xml version="1.0" encousrng="UTF-8"?><usrsclib xmlns="urn:usrsclib"><usr:usrscinfo xmlns:usr="urn:GOT:-;usrscinfo"><usr:site><name>John Smith</name><usr:numSets>1</usr:numSets><usr:setNumber>1</usr:setNumber></usr:site><usr:description><usr:table><usr:siteName siteNumber="1">Main42</usr:siteName></usr:tableOfContents><usr:web href="www" /><usr:web href="www" /></usr:description><usr:city>hin</usr:city></usr:usrscinfo></usrsclib>`

Comment: We don't write code for you, show us what you hav so far.

Comment: "(hopefully) simple" - exactly three lines of code.

Comment: @Stephan - are you including `@echo off` in that? Because with the data that's been given, this is a one-liner assuming the name is hard-coded.

Comment: @EvanCarslake Sorry I'm new at this. So far I have been playing with findstr `for /F "tokens=2 delims=<> %%a in ('findstr "<name>" C:\list.xml') do set name=%%a echo %name%` The original post should say `<NAME>John Smith</NAME>` but I couldn't get the formatting correct. The name may be 3 or 4 words and sometimes contain -

Comment: @egtrev edit this into your post rather than in a comment.

Comment: Could you show us some sample data in context? Telling us it's not necessaily on its own separate line leaves us guessing. Does the data you want always appear on the same line, but not necessarily on its own line, or can the three elements be distributed across more than one line?

Comment: @Magoo `<NAME>John Smith</NAME>` is always together and always on the same line, but not always on its own separate line.

Comment: @SomethingDark yes, one line if you could be sure, `<NAME>John Smith</NAME>` is on it's own line without other tags. My idea was nearly identical to Magoo's. (1. `for` 2. `set` 3. `for`)

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q36630524.txt"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('FINDSTR /i /L /c:"<name>" "%filename1%"') DO SET "name=%%a"
SET "name=%name:*<name>=%"
FOR /f "delims=<" %%a IN ("%name%") DO set "name=%%a"
ECHO "%name%"
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q36630524.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

Read the file, filtering on the only line containing the string `<name>` and assign to `name`.

set that part of `name` which is any number of any characters up to and including the string `<name>` to *nothing*

Use `findstr' to tokenise the resultant string using`<`as a delimiter. Assign token1 to`name`(this will be the name part which precedes the string`

show result.

Comment: Thanks, I get **< was unexpected at this time** when hitting the following section `SET "name=%name:*<name>=%"` I have added example of the XML single line data to original post, if you want to test with that.

Comment: I added your data-line to my testfile. Worked fine for me. Please make sure that you simply cut-and-paste the posted code, then change the file/directoryname only. Batch can show sensitivity to even slight format-changes. Notepad is notorious for trying to "format" text assuming it's a Word-Processor. Ensure the file is saved as ASCII text not Unicode. For preference, use a text editor (I use Editplus (https://www.editplus.com) other use Notepad++.  If still not work, try adding `ECHO "%name%"` on a line before that `set` command to see the `name` being processed. The quotes are critical.

Comment: I set Notepad++ to ASCI and all worked with no errors. Thanks for the help and explaining the steps.

Comment: One additional small problem - some of the names have a - and spaces between like `John - Smith` the issue is the output of the - looks like this `John ΓÇô Smith` (guessing because of the formatting on the XML file I am searching) I have tried the following at the end to try and replace it `set name=%name:ΓÇô=%`  but `ΓÇô` does not get replaced

Comment: The problem here is that `cmd` is poor at non-ASCII characters. The `-` between the names is actually some variety of (uni)code sequence - perhaps originating from a word-processor. If you use a hex editor to view the *actual* byte-sequence, then you could use `sed` or `awk` to change that sequence to `-`. Perhaps if you output the name as processed to a file (`>afilename echo %name%`) ten use a hex editor (google...) to determine the hex sequence to be replaced, then direct the `findstr` output via `sed` like `^|sed s/\xab\xcd/-/g` (ab,cd = hex-chars found) - GNUSED would be a good choice.

Comment: @egtrev: from command line you could `echo ΓÇô>>yourbatch.bat` (copy and paste the characters from screen) - then in your editor copy and paste the string (whatever it may look like) into your `set name=%name:___=%`. It's an ugly workaround, but a quick solution if it's the only "strange sequence" (or if there are only a few of them).